# sql query to with insert select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with the below format:

```
ID  curr    Date                    Bid     Ask
1   AUD/NZD 20090501 00:00:00.833   1.2866  1.28733
2   AUD/NZD 20090501 01:01:01.582   1.28667 1.2874
3   AUD/NZD 20090501 02:01:01.582   1.28667 1.28747
```

Now I need to select the change of Bid and Ask column and store into a different table...The result should be like the following

```
Bid Change  Ask Change  

0.0000700   0.0000700   
0.0000000   0.0000700   


select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.curr, 
    t1.date,
    t1.bid, 
    t1.bid - t2.bid [Bid Change],  
    t1.ask, 
    t1.ask - t2.ask [Ask Change]

from tbltest t1
left join tbltest t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID + 1
order by date
```

This query returns everything correct except the format of Bid Change and Ask Change...like the following

```
 BID Change            ASK CHANGE
7.00000000000145E-05  7.00000000000145E-05
```

Am really clueless on what to do with this situation...any little help will work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which database you using ?

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande its sql

Comment: i measn to say `Mysql` or `sqlserver`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande...sorry its sql server

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Self-join on the condition that will compare the two rows you want to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem necessary to me to store them in a different table, you can just calculate them on the fly using [`APPLY`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), this way any changes to the underlying data will not cause your change data to be stale:

```
SELECT  T.*,
        BidChange = t.Bid - prev.Bid,
        AskChange = t.Ask - prev.Ask
FROM    T
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 T2.Bid, T2.Ask
            FROM    T AS T2
            WHERE   T2.Curr = T.Curr
            AND     T2.Date < T.Date
            ORDER BY T2.Date DESC
        ) AS prev;
```

If this is something you will need regularly then you may want to consider a view, rather than storing it in a table.

---

[image]

Comment: @GarethD...what is the T2 here?

Comment: `T2` is a [table alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - I didn't know your table name so I just used `T`

Comment: I am getting following error...Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'T'.

Comment: As above. I don't know what your actual table is called, so I just used `T`. If you substitute your table name in it should work fine.

Comment: @garethD...for BID change and Ask Change am getting the following value  7.00000000000145E-05 7.00000000000145E-05

Comment: I think this is an issue with your data then - I have posted an image of the query working correctly with your sample data.

Comment: @garethD...I have done some other query which returns me everything only the format of Bid change and Ask change are weird..have posted that query in the post...can you please check that once...please

Comment: @GarethD...have you checked the edited version of post with the query...please help me on the formatting please

Comment: Formatting is a job for the presentation layer, not SQL.. What are you displaying the results in?

Comment: (t1.bid - t2.bid) and (t1.ask - t2.ask)  returning weird format...whereas if i try to add value it returns the exact result!!!

Comment: @GarethD...is it because of the TYPE I have used is FLOAT for the Bid and Ask column?

Comment: Probably. [Float is not always accurate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2100490/1048425) - You may want to cast to decimal.